# Sign in with Apple on Android with Cordova

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, authentication, apple-sign-in

I successfully implemented authentification with Apple ID on my ionic/cordova application for browser and iOS using firebase auth.

[image]

I would like to know if there is a way to allow my users to use this functionality on an Android device.

There is actually two native plugins for apple-sign-in with cordova :

- [cordova-signin-with-apple-plugin](https://github.com/nrikiji/cordova-signin-with-apple-plugin)
- [cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple](https://github.com/twogate/cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple)

But both are only compatible with ios.

According to the [firebase apple-sign-in auth documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/apple), this can be achievable but require some android native code.

Does that mean that the only way to implement this on Cordova would be to create a native plugin ? Or is there another way ?

Thank you

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 1):

Late reply but you need to use the Sign in with Apple JS flow, using the popup option. So from your webview you do the request to Apple first, then you send the Apple response to your server.

Have a look at the docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/configuring_your_webpage_for_sign_in_with_apple